# Setting one Section of HTML as a Different Background Color

Tags: css, html

I have a top dropdown navigation on my website, that I want the background color to be different on. The color of my website background is a grey, while I would like only the tab part to be (ex.) white.

The CSS for my background color is as follows:

```
body{
    background-color:#D0D0D0; margin-right:10%; margin-left:10%; margin-top:0%;
}
```

I would like my dropdown navigation to have a white background while keeping the rest of the page the same. My dropdown is in a header.php file, then referenced in.

My navigation HTML is as follows:

```
<center><nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/arcade">Arcade</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/arcade/action">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/arcade">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/puzzle">Puzzle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/violence">Violence</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/defense">Defense</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/rpg">RPG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Watch</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/watch/tv">TV Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="/watch/movies">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS, of course, styles this header.php.

[This](http://www.gameshank.com) is my website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want. Do you want the parent to be white? Do you want it to be white only if it is a dropdown, or do you want the children within the dropdown to be white...?

Comment: I want the background color of everything in the header (dropdown navigation) to be white. So, like, all of the header document. Everything from the very top of the webpage to just above the GameShank logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS to this:

```
nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px -12.5%;
}
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

If you're not happy with this solution, you are going to need to modify the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Put an id on the nav tag and style the menu over css.

Html:

```
<nav id='nav'> 
    // menu
</nav>
```

Css:

```
#nav {
    background-color: 'white';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just need to set the nav background as white..

in your css:

```
nav { background-color:#fff; }
```

**Extending the full width:**
can also be done with HTML resdesign

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <nav>
         <!-- nav code -->
    </nav>
    <div id="container">
         <!-- all of the rest of your code -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body { }
nav { background-color:#fff; }

#container { 
    background-color:#D0D0D0;
    margin:0px 10%; 
}
```

Comment: I did this, and it worked great! But is there a way to extend the color beyond the margins I've set to 10% on both sides?